# Approximate $e^{n\ln(1-p)}-e^{-np}$ by Taylor approximation

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In our stochastics lecture the professor wrote
$$
\left|e^{n\ln(1-p)}-e^{-np}\right|\approx \frac{e^{-np}}{2}np^2,
$$
where $0<p<1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This approximation can easily be shown by a Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-p)$.

---

I failed to get the approximation.

**My approach:**

The Taylor approximation of $\ln(1-p)$ at point $x_0=1$ is
$$
\ln(x)\approx (x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2},\text{ for all } x\in (0,1)\implies \ln(1-p)\approx -p-\frac{p^2}{2}.
$$

Keeping this in mind, I get
$$
\left|e^{n\ln(1-p)}-e^{-np}\right|\approx \left|e^{n(-p-\frac{p^2}{2})}-e^{-np}\right|=e^{-np}\left|e^{-n\frac{p^2}{2}}-1\right|.
$$

How do I get the approximation $\frac{e^{-np}}{2}np^2$ from that last step?

Comment: For small $|x|$, $|e^x - 1| \approx |x|$ (Using Talyor expansion of $e^x$).

Comment: @sudeep5221, we don't know if $-\frac{np^2}{2}$ is small.

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is in a small interval, the functions $|e^{n\frac{p^2}{2}}-1 \approx np^2|$ since the exponential function gets closer to the input.